# NSMatrix with multiple toggle buttons?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multi-select, nsmatrix, nsbuttoncell

I am trying to create an `NSMatrix` of `NSButtonCell`s where between zero and four buttons can be selected (toggled on).  I have tried the following (test) code, but am not sure how I can provide the functionality I require.  Perhaps it's not possible with `NSMatrix` and I need to look at an alternative control, or create my own?

```
@interface MatrixView : NSView
{
    NSScrollView *_scrollView;
    NSMatrix *_matrixView;
}
@end

@implementation MatrixView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    NSLog(@"initWithFrame. frameRect=%@", NSStringFromRect(frameRect));
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, frameRect.size.width, frameRect.size.height)];
        [_scrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
        [_scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
        [_scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
        [_scrollView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];

        NSSize contentSize = [_scrollView contentSize];
        contentSize.height = 300;

        // Make it 3 x however-many-buttons-will-fit-the-height
        CGFloat gap = 8.0;
        CGFloat width = (contentSize.width / 3.0) - (gap * 2.0);
        NSUInteger rows = (contentSize.height / (width + gap));

        NSLog(@"width=%f, rows=%lu", width, rows);

        NSButtonCell *prototype = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
        [prototype setTitle:@"Hello"];
        [prototype setButtonType:NSToggleButton];
        [prototype setShowsStateBy:NSChangeGrayCellMask];
        _matrixView = [[NSMatrix alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height)
                                                 mode:NSListModeMatrix
                                            prototype:prototype
                                         numberOfRows:rows
                                      numberOfColumns:3];
        [_matrixView setCellSize:NSMakeSize(width, width)];
        [_matrixView setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(gap, gap)];
        [_matrixView setAllowsEmptySelection:YES];
        [_matrixView sizeToCells];
        [_scrollView setDocumentView:_matrixView];
        [self addSubview:_scrollView];
        [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        [prototype release];
    }

    return self;
}

...
```

Comment: You can certainly have a matrix with multiple toggle buttons -- I made one in IB, with NSButtonCells (push on push off type) and the matrix in highlight mode. This showed buttons that stayed highlighted until you pushed them again.  Limiting it to 4 only, is a bit trickier -- haven't completely figured that one out yet.

Comment: @rdelmar I've just changed the code above to use push-on-push-off buttons and to put the matrix into highlight mode, but it doesn't work as desired (the push-on-push-off mode is overridden by the matrix and nothing stays pushed in).  Was there anything else that needed to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with the following subclass of NSMatrix.  I added one property, onCount, to keep track of how many buttons were in the on state:

```
@implementation RDMatrix
@synthesize onCount;

-(id) initWithParentView:(NSView *) cv {
    NSButtonCell *theCell = [[NSButtonCell alloc ]init];
    theCell.bezelStyle = NSSmallSquareBezelStyle;
    theCell.buttonType = NSPushOnPushOffButton;
    theCell.title = @"";
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200,150,1,1) mode:2 prototype:theCell numberOfRows:4 numberOfColumns:4]){ 
        [self setSelectionByRect:FALSE];
        [self setCellSize:NSMakeSize(40,40)];
        [self sizeToCells];
        self.target = self;
        self.action = @selector(buttonClick:);
        self.drawsBackground = FALSE;
        self.autoresizingMask = 8;
        self.allowsEmptySelection = TRUE;
        self.mode = NSHighlightModeMatrix;
        self.onCount = 0;
        [cv addSubview:self];
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}


-(IBAction)buttonClick:(NSMatrix *)sender {
    NSUInteger onOrOff =[sender.selectedCells.lastObject state];
    if (onOrOff) {
        self.onCount += 1;
    }else{
        self.onCount -= 1;
    }
    NSLog(@"%ld",self.onCount);
    if (self.onCount == 5) {
        [sender.selectedCells.lastObject setState:0];
        self.onCount -= 1;
    }    
}
```

When you try to select the 5th button it will flash on, but then go off. This could be a problem depending on how you are using the state of these buttons.  I just logged them with this method:

```
-(IBAction)checkMatrix:(id)sender {
    NSIndexSet *indxs = [self.mat.cells indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSButtonCell *cell, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return cell.state == NSOnState;
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@",indxs);
}
```

After Edit:  I didn't like the way my first method flashed the button on briefly before turning it off again when you try to click the 5th button. I found what I think is a better solution that involves overriding mouseDown in the matrix subclass (if you want to try this, you should delete the setAction and setTarget statements and delete the buttonClick method):

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *) event {
    NSPoint matPoint = [self convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
    NSInteger row;
    NSInteger column;
    [self getRow:&row column:&column forPoint:matPoint];
    NSButtonCell *cell = [self cellAtRow:row column:column];
    if (self.onCount < 4 && cell.state == NSOffState) {
        cell.state = NSOnState;
        self.onCount += 1;
    }else if (cell.state == NSOnState) {
        cell.state = NSOffState;
        self.onCount -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @trojanfoe : I wasn't satisfied with the method I used to limit the number of buttons that can be in the on state, so I came up with what I think is a better solution.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Don't worry I've used different counting code anyway, disabling the unselected buttons when 4 are selected.  The key to your answer is the use of the use of the target method and finding out what button was just pressed.